# Adding CustomHeader in TRESTClient

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to add CustomHeader in my restclient to add an apikey.

In my code I use (FRESTClient is TRESTClient)

```
FRESTClient.SetHTTPHeader('X-XXX-ApiKey', 'fdfd121231212fds');
```

but it is not set in my http header when I see it on fiddler. What is the way to make this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried 'AddParameter'?

```
FRestClient.AddParameter('<Name>', '<Value>', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTClient.AddParameter